# Using Generic Methods to optimize c# code

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

Instead of writing this list of line again and again

```
ScheduleJob<BillingJob>(sched, BillingJob.IntervalInMinutes, 1);
ScheduleJob<MaintenanceUrlTriggerJob>(sched, MaintenanceUrlTriggerJob.IntervalInMinutes, 2);
```

I want some how I make list of jobs then just run loops.... any idea how I can I do this below is Pseudocode having syntax error here `ScheduleJob<obj.GetType()>`

```
var list = new List<Type>();
list.Add(typeof(BillingJob));
list.Add(typeof(MaintenanceUrlTriggerJob));

var jobId = 0;
foreach (var obj in list)
{
    jobId++;

    ScheduleJob<obj.GetType()>(sched, BillingJob.IntervalInMinutes, jobId);
}
```

Comment: You want to store different types in your list?   Maybe you should be using an ArrayList.   Then the problem is when you get an item out of the ArrayList you must figure out what type it is

Comment: There is nothing wrong with storing types that have a common base type in a generic list.

Comment: I didn't say there was.  I was pointing out an option and although the object types have similar names, there is nothing to indicate they have a common base type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but you'll need to use reflection to create the generic type parameter on the fly.

Psuedo code adaption of your code to demonstrate the technique:

```
var list = new List<Type>();
list.Add(typeof(BillingJob));
list.Add(typeof(MaintenanceUrlTriggerJob));

var jobId = 0;
foreach (var jobType in list)
{
    jobId++;

    var method = typeof(QuartzSchedulerClass).GetMethod("ScheduleJob");
    var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(jobType);
    generic.Invoke(this, (Other Params));
}
```

It is probably likely that the creators of Quartz know that this use case with generic methods are a pain, and probably have a overload that takes a type param:

```
ScheduleJob(typeof(Job), etc);
```

Usually, the generic methods are just thin wrappers around this for convenience.

Comment: Just FYI, ScheduleJob is my customized function not Quartz.net function

Comment: Oh, then make it have a overload that takes a Type param instead of using the generic type param.